# Are there any Sorcerer-only spells officially in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, sorcerer

In D&D 3.5 many of the "Dragon-something" sourcebooks had spells that were on Sorcerer spell list, but not on Wizard one. Some of them was dual-purpose, other touched the draconic nature of sorcerer, etc.

Are there any spells like that officially in Pathfinder? Spells only for Sorcerers, preferably interacting with their bloodline powers? I understand they are no longer so much *needed* because Sorcerer now gets his own goodies, but I still would like to know.

Problem with searching for them: Even in D&D, they were listed as "Sorcerer / Wizard" spells, with "sorcerer only spell" in a fine print. So this isn't something I can easily filter out. Or, if I can, I don't know how.

I tried [to Google "sorcerer only" on d20pfsrd.com](https://www.google.com/search?q="sorcerer+only"+site%3Awww.d20pfsrd.com) but I only got results from *Sorcerer’s Options: Beyond Bloodlines. Copyright 2011, Super Genius Games; Author: Owen K.C. Stephens* and I don't know if it is even balanced sourcebook, allowed in organized play etc. I doubt its status as official rulebook for Pathfinder, but that's all the results I found.

Comment: Since that's not really part of the question, let me clarify: No third-party content is allowed in organized play (PFS), even if some of those books are third-party published by actual paizo developers (such as Owen).

Comment: @ShadowKras I'm not going to play organized play any time soon (sadly), I only use organized play rules as a gauge to be sure I don't min-max too much ;) Thanks for clarification, you confirmed that what I was able to find wasn't quite what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is none

Any spell that is granted by a bloodline and not available on the *wizard/sorcerer* spell list should qualify into that criteria, such as *Bless* from the [Celestial Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/celestial-bloodline/). But there are no spells that are exclusively available to sorcerers in general but not also available to wizards.

Only two spells mention *"bloodline"* in their text, [Energy Hack](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Energy%20Hack) and [Tail Strike](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tail%20Strike), but those are also available to wizards. And any spell that mentions *"spontaneous"* spellcasting is merely describing how it works slightly different against spontaneous casters, like [Mindwipe](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mindwipe), [Spellcrash](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spellcrash) or [Spellsteal](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spellsteal). Finally, there are no spells that affect *"known spells"* either.